# MYSQL SUM and UPDATE between tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `items [table]` (contains all the items description and quantity) and `tickets [table]` (also contains the same as items table).

I want to insert a new ticket using my program and that when the ticket reaches the database automatically grabs the new item_description and values, **SUMS** and **UPDATES** the `items [table]`
PS: I'm new to MYSQL.

**Basically:**

```
 **FROM** tickets[table] **USE** item_description as **ID**, **SELECT** quantity and **UPDATE** items[table] quantity **USING** item_description as ID
```

Comment: Seems like a lot of duplication. Is this really necessary?

Comment: Please add table definitions ,sample data and expected outcome as text to the question. NOTE There is no reason to hold a sum in the items table that I can see.

Comment: @P.Salmon I need the SUM so the ticket quantities add to the total quantity in the items database, like stacking, this is for inventory management. The tickets is inventory entry

Comment: @juergend As I said, I'm new to MYSQL, sorry

Comment: If you are determined on this course of action consider a trigger - see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126113/mysql-using-a-trigger-to-update-quantity-on-another-table-if-part-is-used

Comment: @P.Salmon very helpful, thank you !